# This command has to be run under the root user. But I am root only

Tags: ansible, root, rhel

I have a simple playbook that tries to install packages.
My task is failing(see output).

I can ping the host, and manually I can run the command as the super user(`tco`).

my `ansible.cfg`

```
[defaults]
inventory = /Users/<myuser>/<automation>/ansible/inventory
remote_user = tco
```

`packages`

```
packages:
  - yum-utils
  - sshpass
```

`playbook`

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - vars/packages.yml
  tasks:
    - name: testing connection
      ping:
      remote_user: tco

    - name: Installing packages
      yum:
        name: "{{ packages }}"
        state: present
```

Running playbook:
`ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --limit master --become --ask-become-pass --become-user=tco --become-method=sudo`

Output:

```
ansible-playbook register_sys_rh.yml --limit master --become --ask-become-pass --become-user=tco --become-method=sudo
BECOME password: 

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xx.xxx.13.105]

TASK [testing connection] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xx.xxx.13.105]

TASK [Installing packages] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [xx.xxx.13.105]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "This command has to be run under the root user.", "results": []}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
xx.xxx.13.105              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

inventory:

```
ansible-inventory --list | jq '.master'
{
  "hosts": [
    "xx.xxx.13.105"
  ]
}
```

I have copied my `id_rsa.pub` to the host already. I cannot loging to the host without a password.
I can log in and do `sudo su` or run any other command that needs root privilege.

```
[tco@control-plane-0 ~]$ whoami
tco
[tco@control-plane-0 ~]$ hostname -I
xx.xxx.13.105 192.168.122.1 
[tco@control-plane-0 ~]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for tco: 
[root@control-plane-0 tco]#
```

I explicitly override user, sudo_method through ansible_cli, no idea what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you copied your ssh key to authorized hosts but it isnt working? verify permissions on ~/.ssh/* .... chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/* and sii if you can login with the key. if not try ssh -vvv abd review the debug output to see what isn't working

Comment: `--become-user=root`, which is the default so you can simplify omit it.  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

Comment: yeah i wanted to override explicitly that's why i provided all those flags.

Comment: Command line values have the lowest [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) over all other places where you can define a var (except extra vars which have the highest precedence). Moreover pay attention to the variable names as your auto answer contains several typos. You can read: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

Comment: I removed everything from cfg and passed everything through command line, like this: `ansible-playbook main.yml -i scripts/inventory --become-user=tco --become -K  --become-method=sudo` and entering the password for `tco` user only and get the same error `This command has to be run under the root user`

Comment: the weird thing is I cannot ssh manually to the host with `root/<password>` which I provide to ansible. If I pass `root/tco-password` and download some files I see the user as `root` for those files when I do `ls -ll`. Not sure what is happening and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.
But, I need to understand the Ansible concept better.

I changed `ansible.cfg` to this(changed `become_user` to `root`)

```
[defaults]
inventory = <my-inventory-path>
remote_user = tco

[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_method=sudo
become_ask_pass=False
become_user=root
become_pass=<password>
```

And, running it like this:

`ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --limit master`
this gives me an error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
```

So, I run like this:

`ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml  --limit master --ask-become-pass`
and when a password is prompted I provide `tco` password not sure what is the password for the `root` user is.

**And this works.**

Not sure why cfg file password is not working, even though I provide the same password when prompted.

As per my understanding, when I say become_user and become_pass that is what ansible uses to run privilege commands. But, here I am saying `remote_user: tco` and `become_user:root`

Comment: become_user is what account ansible needs to sudo to (default is root, so it can be omitted) `become_pass` does not exist, the variable is named `ansible_become_pass`. `remote_user` is the account to which ansible connects via ssh, in your case is `tco`, so after ssh when ansible does excalation, it needs the `tco` account password, thus that's the password that goes into `ansible_become_pass`

Comment: => become_pass**word**

Comment: this explains why i had to enter pwd manually

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the playbook is unable to run on the remote nodes as a root user.
We can modify the ansible.cfg file in order to resolve this issue.
Steps:

1. Open the ansible.cfg, default command is:  sudo vim /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
2. Search for regular expression: /privilege_escalation ( / is basically searching for the keyword that follows in VIM)
3. Press I (Insert mode), uncomment following lines:

   [privilege_escalation]
   become=True
   become_method=sudo
   become_user=root
   become_ask_pass=False

Note: If the .cfg lines are not modified, the corresponding values can be passed via Terminal during the playbook execution(as specified in the question itself).

4. Run the playbook again with: ansible-playbook playbookname.yml

Note, if there is no ssh authentication pre-established between the Ansible controller and the nodes, appending -kK is required (this asks for the privileged user password for the remote nodes )  i.e. ansible-playbook playbookname.yml -kK
This will require you to input password for the SSH connection, as well as the BECOME password(the password for the privileged user on the node)